# looping in argtype and argaction function

Tags: r, function, loops

Have just created an account here because I finally have a question worth asking. I am pretty new to R (1 year, on-off user) but have usually been able to find answers to my R questions online until now. My question is somewhat convoluted so I will try to be as clear as possible. Apologies if my terminology is not on point.

I have a dataframe with two columns, one old ID numbers and two conservation feature names. E.g.:

```
> df =
> code    attr
> 1       FSM Oceanic atoll
> 3       FSM Oceanic bank
> 1       Palau Oceanic atoll
> 3       Palau Oceanic bank
```

As you can see, these features are unique but not in terms of their old coding system. I need to create a new column with new unique ID codes. For e.g.:

```
> df =
> code  attr                  new.code
> 1     FSM Oceanic atoll     1
> 3     FSM Oceanic Bank      2
> 1     Palau Oceanic atoll   3
> 3     Palau Oceanic Bank    4
```

I found a way to do this from a previous question:

```
> newCodes <- function(argtype, argaction){ 
>    if (argtype==1 & argaction=="FSM Oceanic atoll")
>       return(1)
>    if (argtype==3 & argaction=="FSM Oceanic Bank")
>       return(2)
>    if (argtype==1 & argaction=="Palau Oceanic atoll")
>       return(3)
>    if (argtype==3 & argaction=="Palau Oceanic Bank")
>       return(4)
>    } # Defines my function
>
> df$new.code <- mapply(newCodes, df$code, df$attr) # Creates the new conditional column
```

The reason it needs to be done this way is because my original dataframe has many duplicate entries of the same "unique features", which need to be maintained for my purposes (it is essentially an attribute table of a shapefile, hence the duplicate entries).

The above function code is great when I have just a few features (like 10), but at some point I will need to do this for tables with up to 185 unique features. I was wondering if it were possible to loop the function above, so that I don't have to manually type out the individual "argtypes" and "argactions" for each feature? I feel like there might be a way to loop this based on the initial dataframe frame that I've got (i.e. the first dataframe I gave the example of). I don't know what it would look like in code but would mean something along the lines of:

```
> if (argtype == [loop: through each old code number row by row in the initial "code"
> column in 1st df] & argaction == [loop: through each corresponding attribute name row
> by row in the initial "attr" column in 1st df])
>    return([loop: just loop through each row value of a df with the new code IDs,
> which would be just 1 to x, x being number of new ID codes needed])
```

Really hope what I mean is clear. Thanks for any advice on this.

Comment: what do you mean by "two conservation features" ? What happened if you have duplicated line ? same new.code value? for each couple (code, attr) which is not duplicated you want a unique new code value, correct?

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear with my punctuation there - I was just explaining the first dataframe that had two columns, one column being old ID numbers and the second column being conservation features (i.e. habitat features of interest that I want to conserve) ... Yes if I have any duplicated lines (like in the first dataframe example I gave here), I would like the new.code values to be the same; they should match. And yes, for each code/attr couple which is not duplicated I would like a unique new code value. Thanks @ColonelBeauvel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
transform(df, new.code=as.numeric(factor(attr)))
```

This gives every unique term in attr a number and the numbering is alphabetical. It uses the fact that if you convert a factor to a number it gives you an integer referring to the levels of the factor. I hope this helps.
Cheers

Comment: Is it possible to be able to include the old code column as well, in order to assign the unique terms? I need the new code values to represent unique combinations of both the old code and attr columns. Thanks so much for your time and help, cheers

Comment: `transform(df, new.code=as.numeric(factor(paste(code, attr))))`

The new paste part creates a character which consists of the number and the name. Hence you get results for all the unique combinations. I hope this helps.